# Almacenar caracteres unicode en Bundle

Tags: java, archivo-de-propiedades, i18n

Tengo un proyecto de [java](/questions/tagged/java) internacionalizado y versionado, pero parece que al abrirlo los caracteres con acentos del *resource bundle* ( el archivo .properties ) del idioma español se ve de manera incorrecta.

Ya intenté cambiarle la codificación, pero parece no ser la mejor solución.

[image: Pantallazo]

¿De qué forma puedo lograr una internacionalización consistente con mis colaboradores que tienen otra codificación diferente a la mía?

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que tu archivo está codificado en UTF 8? Porque al abrirlo desde tu IDE se pierden los caracteres con tilde.

Comment: Sí, de hecho tengo un plugin que estoy ayudando a desarrollar para abrir y guardar en distintas codificaciones

Comment: buen día, puedes publicar como estas abriendo los archivos, me imagino son de texto.

Comment: Pues no parece. Quizás tu IDE cambie la codificación sin que lo notes. O quizás tu OS tenga una codificación de caracteres distinta. O quizás la herramienta que utilizas para compilar y construir tu proyecto cambie la codificación de los archivos e.g. maven lo puede cambiar pero tu puedes indicar que los archivos estén codificados con UTF-8 por defecto utilizando el property `<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La causa de tu problema es que los archivos .properties deben estar [codificados en ISO 8859-1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html):

> Los métodos load(Reader) / store(Writer, String) cargan y almacenan propiedades desde y hacia un flujo basado en caracteres en un formato simple y orientado a líneas especificado posteriormente. El par de métodos load(InputStream) / store(OutputStream, String) trabajan de la misma manera que el par load(Reader)/store(Writer, String), excepto que el flujo de entrada/salida está **codificado mediante la codificación de caracteres ISO 8859-1**. Los caracteres que no pueden ser representados directamente en esta codificación pueden ser escritos usando *Unicode escapes* como está definido en la sección 3.3 de La Especificación del Lenguaje Java™ ; solamente un único caracter 'u' está permitido en una secuencia de escape. La herramienta *native2ascii* puede ser usada para convertir archivos de propiedades desde y hacia otras codificaciones de caracteres.

La mayoría de los *frameworks* los leen así. Desconozco si hay alguno que los lea en XML, los cuales sí pueden ser UTF-8.

La solución puede ser convertirlos a ISO 8859-1.

---

Olvidé comentarte. Para agregar caracteres que no puedan codificarse en ISO 8859-1 (o sea, la mayoría de los caracteres definidos en Unicode) puedes usar la sintaxis `\uNNNN`. [Más información aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html) .

Comment: Hola ¿podrías traducir aunque sea de forma resumida el texto en inglés? Saludos

Comment: @Gepser Lo hice, en la parte superior, en el primer enunciado. Pero adelante, esta comunidad es un esfuerzo colaborativo en donde todos podemos editar.

Comment: Claro, no lo hice porque esto lo vi desde la cola de revisión y no suelo hacer eso desde allí. Como sea me pareció una buena respuesta y por eso el upvote. Me gustaría traducir el texto completo pero lo haré en unas horas si nadie lo ha hecho aún. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Y no sabes si con la herramienta que dices se convierten los carcateres que no sean parte del ISO 8859-1?

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Yo suelo usar Notepad++: abro el archivo, y en el menú Codificación selecciono ANSI. Pero los caracteres que no sean ISO 8859-1 se reemplazan con "?". Recuerdo que Netbeans una vez cambió todo a \uNNNN pero no supe cómo lo hice.

Comment: Exactamente eso me pasó, y allí empezaron los problemas, pues detectaban unicode y me lo pasaba a utf8. Voy a cambiarle al codificación a la que me dices esperando que funcione. Saludos! :)

Comment: El uso de los caracteres con diagonales solucionó todo y me permitió que si alguien tiene otra codificación el proceso fuera transparente.

Answer (score 1):

He tenido el mismo problema abriendo archivos que contienen caracteres acentuados, lo que se realiza es usar la codificación `UTF-8` al abrirlo:

```
bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: La solución que da @Elenasys a mi me funcionó, ya que al usarlo por defecto abre el fichero para lectura con la codificación por defecto de la propiedad de sistema "file.encoding".
Y por ampliar un poco más, puede usar la siguiente función para averiguar la codificación: `String defaultCharacterEncoding = System.getProperty("file.encoding")' `

Comment: Desafortunadamente esta solución no carga dinámicamente el bundle del locale correcto en cada caso

Comment: Bueno al final es lo que te comentamos, tienes que agregar el encoding   "UTF-8" para poder extraer los datos correctamente.