# Problema tildes y caracteres especiales java

Tags: java, jsp, archivo-de-propiedades

Tengo un problemilla con las tildes  y caracteres especiales en un proyecto Java en Eclipse. Es un proyecto importado y ya lo he configurado en Eclipse en Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Text file encoding y Content Types -> Text -> Deafult encoding y está puesto en UTF-8 y nada. El contenido que no se carga correctamente está en un archivo .properties con el siguiente código:

```
   NLS_INCLUDES=com.documentum.webcomponent.library.locator.LocatorContainerNlsProp
MSG_TITLE_LANZAR_WF=Crear Lote
MSG_UN=Unidad de Negocio / Área
MSG_COD_UN=Código de Negocio / Actividad
MSG_RESP_LOTE=Responsable Lote
MSG_TIPO_LOTE=Tipo de Lote
MSG_LOCALIZADOR=Localizador

MSG_MUST_HAVE_NAME=El campo debe estar relleno.

MSG_TITLE= Crear Lote 
MSG_OBJECT=

MSG_IS_REQUIERED=El campo es requerido

MSG_OK=OK
MSG_CANCEL=Cancel
MSG_OK_TIP=OK
MSG_CANCEL_TIP=Cancel
```

Posteriormente, en un  jsp se muestra la información:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" %>
<%@ page import='com.mppan.workflow.LanzarWF' %>
<%@ page errorPage="/wdk/errorhandler.jsp" %>

<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/dmform_1_0.tld" prefix="dmf" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/dmformext_1_0.tld" prefix="dmfx" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/dmformext_1_0.tld" prefix="dmfx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"          "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<dmf:html>
<dmf:head>
<dmf:webcontainerrequirements/>
<dmf:webform/>
<dmf:title><dmf:label nlsid="MSG_TITLE_LANZAR_WF"/></dmf:title>
</dmf:head>

<dmf:form>
<div><dmf:label cssclass='dialogTitle' nlsid='MSG_TITLE_LANZAR_WF'/>            </div>
<html>

<body>

<table>



    <tr>    
        <td class="leftAlignment"><dmf:label name='lblUnWF'      nlsid='MSG_UN' style="font-weight:bold"/>: </td>
        <td><dmf:dropdownlist name='<%= LanzarWF.CTRL_TXT_UN %>'     width='300'/> 
    <dmf:requiredfieldvalidator     name='<%=LanzarWF.CTRL_REQUIRED_FIELD_CTRL_TXT_UN%>' controltovalidate="<%=     LanzarWF.CTRL_TXT_UN%>" nlsid="MSG_IS_REQUIERED" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>    
        <td><dmf:label name='lblCodUnWF'  nlsid='MSG_COD_UN' style="font-weight:bold"/>:</td> 
        <td align='left'><dmf:dropdownlist name= '<%=     LanzarWF.CTRL_TXT_COD_UN %>' width='300'/> 
        <dmf:requiredfieldvalidator     name='<%=LanzarWF.CTRL_REQUIRED_FIELD_CTRL_TXT_COD_UN%>'     controltovalidate="<%= LanzarWF.CTRL_TXT_COD_UN%>" nlsid="MSG_IS_REQUIERED"     /></td>                        
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="leftAlignment"><dmf:label name='lblRsepLoteWF'     nlsid='MSG_RESP_LOTE' style="font-weight:bold"/>:</td>
        <td align='left'><dmf:text name='<%= LanzarWF.CTRL_TXT_RESP_LOTE %>'  size='60' enabled='false'/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>    
        <td class="leftAlignment"><dmf:label name='lblTipoLoteWF'  nlsid='MSG_TIPO_LOTE' style="font-weight:bold"/>:</td> 
        <td align='left'><dmf:dropdownlist name='<%= LanzarWF.CTRL_TXT_TIPO_LOTE %>' width='300'/> 
        <dmf:requiredfieldvalidator name='<%=LanzarWF.CTRL_REQUIRED_FIELD_CTRL_TXT_TIPO_LOTE%>' controltovalidate="<%= LanzarWF.CTRL_TXT_TIPO_LOTE%>" nlsid="MSG_IS_REQUIERED" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="leftAlignment"><dmf:label name='lblLocalizadorWF' nlsid='MSG_LOCALIZADOR' style="font-weight:bold"/>:</td>
        <td align='left'><dmf:text name='<%= LanzarWF.CTRL_TXT_LOCALIZADOR %>'  size='60'/>
        </td>
    </tr>



</table>
</body>
</html>
</dmf:form>
</dmf:html>
```

Adjunto foto del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A ver si me podéis echar un cable que ya no sé qué tocar.

Muchísimas gracias y saludos!!

Comment: deberias abrir otra pregunta, no editar una existente para preguntar otra cosa

Comment: por cierto, tambien deberias aceptar la respuesta correcta o especificar una correcta tu mismo

Comment: Disculpa, es que no estoy muy puesto aún. Ya lo he modificado y lo he puesto en un hilo nuevo. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: A mi me funciono esto: [https://dtrinf.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/como-escribir-enes-n-y-acentos-en-java/](https://dtrinf.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/como-escribir-enes-n-y-acentos-en-java/)
Espero es sirva.

Comment: Posiblemente relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1214/almacenar-caracteres-unicode-en-bundle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes modificar `<%@ page contentType="text/html" %>` por  `<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>`, ya con eso no deberías de tener problemas

Comment: Esta respuesta creo que solo es válida cuando se esta trabajando con jsp, para otros casos, por ejemplo cuando se esta trabajando con una biblioteca REST hay que cumplir con la codificación ISO 8859-1 como indica @pablo-lozano

Answer (score 3):

Los archivos *.properties, cuando son leídos por Java, tienen **siempre** que cumplir con la codificación `ISO 8859-1`:

> `public void load(InputStream inStream) throws IOException`
>
> Reads a property list (key and element pairs) from the input byte
>   stream. The input stream is in a simple line-oriented format as
>   specified in load(Reader) and is assumed to use the ISO 8859-1
>   character encoding; that is each byte is one Latin1 character.
>   Characters not in Latin1, and certain special characters, are
>   represented in keys and elements using Unicode escapes as defined in
>   section 3.3 of The Java™ Language Specification.

Debes escapar los caracteres no estándar. Una forma cómoda de hacerlo en Eclipse es usando el plugin [ResourceBundle Editor](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/resourcebundle-editor), que lo hace automáticamente.

Comment: Me funcionó muy bien ese plugin la verdad. En mi caso yo ya tenia un fichero de recursos, lo abrí con el editor que incorpora el plugin y al hacer cualquier cambio si vuelves a guardar te convierte ya todos los caracteres especiales