# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir por consola carácteres japoneses?

Tags: java

¿Cómo se hace para que Java imprima por consola carácter japoneses?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("始めましてエヅアドともうどぞよろしくおねがいします");
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero es dar una traducción a japonés. No sé cómo hacer que Java soporte los dos silabarios y los cerca de 4,000 kanjis (jeroglifo japonés).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4067667/13419694

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Almacenar caracteres unicode en Bundle](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1214/almacenar-caracteres-unicode-en-bundle)

Comment: Gracias, tarde un poco, pero ya resolví el problema con lo que me enviaron.

Comment: Ahora, ¿cómo marco que la pregunta se ha resuelto si no me sale la palomita?